# Cycles Render does not reflect camera view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I'm new to Blender, so not sure of the terminology.

I'm having a problem/misunderstanding with Blender 2.73, using the "Cycles Render" engine.

When I render a single frame to a .png file, I am seeing a model with missing detail compared to the Camera view in render mode.  I've looked through and experimented with the setting in the render property sheet, but cannot seem to bring the detail back.  Below are the images:

Rendered Image:
[image: Rendered Output Image]

Camera View (rendered):
[image: Camera Rendered View]

Original Solid View:
[image: Solid VIew]

I'd be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction.  I'm not sure what additional settings I'd need to share.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: If Jerryno's awnser doesn't work for you, you should consider uploading a .blend that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The visibility setting is different for viewport an render, check if the visibility is setup correctly for all objects

[image]

This also applies for modifiers, so if that din't help check that also.

Comment: Just to clarify what the icons do: the **Eye** icon determines the visibility on the **Viewport** and the **Camera** Icon determines if the object will be **Rendered**

Comment: Thanks Jerryno and cegaton, that works.  I'll dig into some more tutorials to avoid these kind of silly Q's in future

Comment: I have an issue regarding activating cameras. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108064/changing-active-camera-will-yield-an-incorrect-rendering)? I need some urgent help and I think you might be able to help me with it. Really appreciate you.